# How to insert a constant string into a text file in every line after N characters in bash

Tags: bash, file, awk, sed

i need a bash or awk or sed solution in order to insert a string in every line of a file , after N spaces

for example i want this file

```
Nov 30 23:09:39.029313 sad asdadfahfgh
Nov 30 23:09:39.029338 ads dsfgdsfgdf
Nov 30 23:09:46.246912 hfg sdasdsa
Nov 30 23:09:46.246951 jghjgh dfgdfgdf
```

to be

```
Nov 30 23:09:39.029313 my_constant_string sad asdadfahfgh
Nov 30 23:09:39.029338 my_constant_string ads dsfgdsfgdf
Nov 30 23:09:46.246912 my_constant_string hfg sdasdsa
Nov 30 23:09:46.246951 my_constant_string jghjgh dfgdfgdf
```

I tried the following but does not work:

```
awk '{print $2" "$3" "$4" crit { for(i=5;i<NF;i++) print $i}}' log_file
```

Comment: post your attempts

Comment: i tried cat log_file | awk '{print $2" "$3" "$4" crit { for(i=5;i<NF;i++) print $i}}' but does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with GNU `sed`

```
$ sed 's/ / xxx /3' file

Nov 30 23:09:39.029313 xxx sad asdadfahfgh
Nov 30 23:09:39.029338 xxx ads dsfgdsfgdf
Nov 30 23:09:46.246912 xxx hfg sdasdsa
Nov 30 23:09:46.246951 xxx jghjgh dfgdfgdf
```

Comment: this is clever! You can say `sed 's/./&HELLO/23' file` and you will be done, since it will append "HELLO" after the 23rd character.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this;

```
awk '{$4="my_constant_string "$4; print $0}' yourFile
```

or

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=3;i++) printf "%s ", $i ;printf "my_constant_string " ; for (i=4;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s ", $i; printf "\n" }'
```

Test

```
$ awk '$4="my_constant_string " $4' test
Nov 30 23:09:39.029313 my_constant_string sad asdadfahfgh
Nov 30 23:09:39.029338 my_constant_string ads dsfgdsfgdf
Nov 30 23:09:46.246912 my_constant_string hfg sdasdsa
Nov 30 23:09:46.246951 my_constant_string jghjgh dfgdfgdf
```

Comment: `awk '$4="my_constant_string " $4' file`

Comment: No you don't need to update, your original answer is easy to understand. what I put in comment is a trick. also if OP want to add a string `"0"` then it may fail. so yours was good.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add content after a fixed number of characters, not on a specific column, use `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/^.{23}/&HELLO /' file

sed 's/^.\{23\}/&HELLO /' file  # equivalent, without -r
```

This catches the first 23th characters on the line and prints them back.

This returns:

```
Nov 30 23:09:39.029313 HELLO sad asdadfahfgh
Nov 30 23:09:39.029338 HELLO ads dsfgdsfgdf
Nov 30 23:09:46.246912 HELLO hfg sdasdsa
Nov 30 23:09:46.246951 HELLO jghjgh dfgdfgdf
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert your string after last digit in line with sed:

```
$ sed 's/.*[0-9]/& my_constant_string/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Gnu awk you could:

```
$ awk 'sub(/^.{22}/,  "& my_constant_string")' file
Nov 30 23:09:39.029313 my_constant_string sad asdadfahfgh
Nov 30 23:09:39.029338 my_constant_string ads dsfgdsfgdf
Nov 30 23:09:46.246912 my_constant_string hfg sdasdsa
Nov 30 23:09:46.246951 my_constant_string jghjgh dfgdfgdf
```

Since the regex `.{22}` only works in Gnu awk with other versions one should:

```
$ awk 'sub(/^....................../,  "& my_constant_string")' file
```

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,"my_constant_string",$4,$5}' file

Nov 30 23:09:39.029313 my_constant_string sad asdadfahfgh
Nov 30 23:09:39.029338 my_constant_string ads dsfgdsfgdf
Nov 30 23:09:46.246912 my_constant_string hfg sdasdsa
Nov 30 23:09:46.246951 my_constant_string jghjgh dfgdfgdf
```